# PDF Creator - Difference in the PDF Quality vs Adobe Acrobat. How can I change it?

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe

When I am using PDF Creator to create PDF documents the quality of the fonts is not exactly the same as when I am using Adobe Acrobat to create the same PDF. The fonts when creating with pdf creator are a bit more fussy (not as crispy as with Adobe).

Does anyone know if/how I can resolve this?

Here are 2 example documents that demonstrate what I mean:

[Example of PDF created with PDF Creator](http://sites.google.com/site/examplefiles/pdf-creator/fonts-pdfcreator.pdf)

[Example of PDF created with Adobe Acrobat](http://sites.google.com/site/examplefiles/pdf-creator/fonts-acrobat.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution for you unfortunately but I can tell you that what you are seeing is anti-aliasing. If anti-aliasing is enabled, fonts at lower resolutions will get that "fuzziness" that some people believe helps with reading. It might not look as pretty but it improves word recognition (so the theory goes). But that's beside the point. What you need to do is [look for a setting](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/pdfcreator-user-manual) to disable anti-aliasing. If you can't find it then you might have to look into setting actual [Ghostscript](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/ghostscript-settings) settings, possibly `dTextAlphaBits` but I'm not a Ghostscript expert.

You can tell its anti-aliasing because the "fuzziness" only appears when the fonts are small. Once you zoom in it all goes away.

**Image zoomed out:**

[image]

**Image zoomed in**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did not realize that when you zoom in the problem does not exist. However, I could not find any setting in PDF Creator to deactivate this behaviour.